# Proof that $a^p-a$ is divisible by $p$ where $p$ is a prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

What is a proof that $a^p-a$ is divisible by $p$ where $p$ is a prime number?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Answer (score 0):

This is Fermat little theorem. You can prove it by using Binomial theorem and/or induction.

Also you can find it here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: Just commented :P

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed lil' Fermat.  I like the group theory proof best, probably.  Though that proof may be over your head at this point.  Let me know if you want to see it.